# 301 redirect with part of the URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I changed a category URL in my shop. The category has many subcategories, which have a lot of products.

The category url:
www.example.com/samsung-galaxy.html

Subcategories within this category have this url:
www.example.com/samsung-galaxy/sample-category.html
And products within subcategories:
www.example.com/samsung-galaxy/sample-category/sample-product.html

I want to change the "samsung-galaxy" bit for other phrase, so that we will have:

The category url:
www.example.com/lg-cookie.html

Subcategories within this category have this url:
www.example.com/lg-cookie/sample-category.html
www.example.com/lg-cookie/sample-category/sample-product.html

How can it be achieve via .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this 301 redirect to the top of the htaccess file in your docuemnt root, while preserving any subcategories or products:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/samsung-galaxy(\.html|/.*)$ /lg-cookie$1
```

If you're already using mod_rewrite, then you may want to stick with using that rather than mod_alias (which `RedirectMatch` belongs to):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^samsung-galaxy(\.html|/.*)$ /lg-cookie$1 [L,R=301]
```